# MyBatis Dynamic SQL join on subquery

Tags: join, subquery, mybatis, dynamic-sql

I want to do something like this in MyBatis Dynamic SQL:

```sql
SELECT id FROM foo
JOIN (SELECT foo_id ...) bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
WHERE ...
```

However, the [`join()`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/blob/8222fb2e19ccb39716e799bd34c147b31563e157/src/main/java/org/mybatis/dynamic/sql/select/AbstractQueryExpressionDSL.java#L49) function only accepts `SqlTable` as an argument.

Is it possible to join on a subquery with MyBatis Dynamic SQL? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyBatis Dynamic SQL doesn't support these types of sub-queries right now. I'll think about adding it.

Comment: This is now supported as of version 1.3.0. See this page in the documentation for details: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/subQueries.html

Answer (score 0):

What's your database?
Do you really need to explicitly use JOIN like this?
Can't you do it just ike this?

SELECT id FROM foo , (select foo_id...) bar
WHERE foo.id = bar.foo_id

Comment: I don't remember the specifics anymore.  But this question is about mybatis dynamic SQL. How would you do that with mybatis dynamic SQL?